# JAVAFX event triggered when selecting a check box

Tags: javafx

My JavaFx FXML application has an issue.

When I select a checkbox on a form, I want to execute a method based on the checkbox that was clicked. Is there any way that I can pass the name of the checkbox through to the method so I can perform some conditional work on it?

I have two checkboxes and only one can be selected. When I click on one, the other should be de-selected and vice versa. Obviously the code below will not work so I am looking to pass the name of the object that was clicked.

Any help would be appreciated,
many thanks.

```
@FXML private void updateRcs(){

    if (chkRcsuri.isSelected()){
        chkRcsuri2.setSelected(false);
    }

    if (chkRcsuri2.isSelected()){
        chkRcsuri.setSelected(false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 37):

You can use change tracking or use Event handling mechanism of JavaFX.
With checkboxes like this,

```
final CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox("chk 1");
final CheckBox chk2 = new CheckBox("chk 2");
```

Change tracking

```
chk1.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        chk2.setSelected(!newValue);
    }
});

chk2.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        chk1.setSelected(!newValue);
    }
});
```

Using event handling

```
EventHandler eh = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() instanceof CheckBox) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
            System.out.println("Action performed on checkbox " + chk.getText());
            if ("chk 1".equals(chk.getText())) {
                chk2.setSelected(!chk1.isSelected());
            } else if ("chk 2".equals(chk.getText())) {
                chk1.setSelected(!chk2.isSelected());
            }
        }
    }
};

chk1.setOnAction(eh);
chk2.setOnAction(eh);
```

Answer (score 9):

Wouldn't radio buttons give you a mutually exclusive selection?  Just make sure you set the groupname to be the same - selecting one would then automatically de-select the other and you can just put additional logic in the Action event.

Better than trying to re-write same functionality around checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

So I was trying to do a similar thing, except I had multiple checkboxes and then one that would be nonsensical to have selectable in conjuction with the others. I made two seperate listeners and set one general purpose one to the main boxes, and a specialized one to the exception.

```
@FXML private CheckBox redCB = new CheckBox();
@FXML private CheckBox blueCB = new CheckBox();
@FXML private CheckBox greenCB = new CheckBox();
@FXML private CheckBox whiteCB = new CheckBox();
@FXML private CheckBox blackCB = new CheckBox();
@FXML private CheckBox colorlessCB = new CheckBox();

//assigning listeners
redCB.selectedProperty().addListener(colorCheckChange);
blueCB.selectedProperty().addListener(colorCheckChange);
greenCB.selectedProperty().addListener(colorCheckChange);
whiteCB.selectedProperty().addListener(colorCheckChange);
blackCB.selectedProperty().addListener(colorCheckChange);
colorlessCB.selectedProperty().addListener(colorlessCheckChange);
                       //note: this is the only different one^^^

//making listeners
ChangeListener colorCheckChange = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
        Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
        if (new_val)
            colorlessCB.setSelected(false);
    }};
ChangeListener colorlessCheckChange = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
        Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
        if (new_val)
        {
            redCB.setSelected(false);
            blueCB.setSelected(false);
            greenCB.setSelected(false);
            blackCB.setSelected(false);
            whiteCB.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
};
```

The first one basically just makes sure that `colorlessCB` isn't selected while trying to select the other colors, and vice verca. This way you also avoid the problem of de-selecting one, and the other one automatically reselecting itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. But be sure about the `a` variable to be appropriate for you

```java
//First in FXML file 
<CheckBox fx:id="chkbxAuto" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#autoConfig" text="Auto" />

// in controler  
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {
    private static int a = 0;
    //references to lables
    ....
    @FXML
    private Label lblStateValue; 
    @FXML
    private Group grpSetting; // a group of elements which I want to be disabled and enabled 
    ... 
    @FXML
    private void autoConfig(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Configing automatically"); 
             a++;
             if(a%2==1){
                 lblStateValue.setText("Auto configuration enabled"); // it change a lable to show the state 
                 grpSetting.setDisable(true); // it disable a group of elements
             }
            else{
                 lblStateValue.setText("Auto configuration disabled");
                 grpSetting.setDisable(false);
             }
            a%=10;

        }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old, but I found when looking for the same problem. I found a solution which

**a)** seems clearer (at least to me comparing to the listener definition) for reading source code and

**b)** Defining a changeListener on a checkBox gave me some problems.

Anyway my solution was to define an onAction function for the checkbox.

```
yourCheckboxName.setOnAction(this::aFunctionName);
...
void aFunctionName() {

    if(yourCheckboxName.isSelected()) {            
        doThis()
    } else {
        doThat()
    }
}
```

**Attention** This needs Java8 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above options take advantage of the most commpact lambda expresions that can be used to add this very repetitive listeners.

Let suppose you have two checkboxes:

```java
chk1.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> chk2.setSelected(!newValue));

chk2.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> chk1.setSelected(!newValue));
```