# javafx - checkbox unchecked when i scroll tableview

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView, in which when I scroll down the table the checked checkboxes are unchecked. The `TableColumn` containing the CheckBox is `col` and is defined as :

```
final TableColumn col = new TableColumn("Select");
col.setCellValueFactory( new Callback<CellDataFeatures<pojo, CheckBox>, ObservableValue<CheckBox>>() {
     @Override
     public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(CellDataFeatures<pojo, CheckBox> arg0) {
       final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

       checkBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
             @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
                TableCellSkin tcs = (TableCellSkin)checkBox.getParent();
                TableCell tc = (TableCell)tcs.getSkinnable();
                TableRowSkin trs = (TableRowSkin)tc.getParent();
                TableRow tr = trs.getParent()!=null ? (TableRow) trs.getParent(): (TableRow)trs.getSkinnable();
                pojo obj = (pojo) tr.getItem();

                if(checkBox.isSelected()){
                    list.add(obj);
                }else{
                    if(list!=null && !list.isEmpty()){
                        list.remove(obj);
                    }
                }
             }
         });
         return new SimpleObjectProperty(checkBox);
     }
 });
```

Comment: are you sure you need to attach an EventHandler on the Check Boxes ? check this approach http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/checkbox.htm or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726824/javafx-event-triggered-when-selecting-a-check-box

Comment: I think you want a checkbox column to select multiple rows, setCellValueFactory is wrong approach for this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example of how to add a checkbox column which works in corporate with selection model of tableview. The selection mode is set to multiple, so you can select multiple items by CTRL + Mouse_Click:

```
public class TableViewSelectColumnDemo extends Application
{

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person( "Jacob", "Smith" ),
                    new Person( "Isabella", "Johnson" ),
                    new Person( "Ethan", "Williams" ),
                    new Person( "Emma", "Jones" ),
                    new Person( "Michael", "Brown" )
            );


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }


    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage )
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene( new Group() );
        stage.setWidth( 450 );
        stage.setHeight( 500 );

        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode( SelectionMode.MULTIPLE );

        List list = new ArrayList();

        TableColumn selectCol = new TableColumn( "Select" );
        selectCol.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: center" );

        selectCol.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>()
                {
                    public TableCell call( TableColumn p )
                    {
                        return new TableCell()
                        {
                            private final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();


                            @Override
                            public void updateItem( Object item, boolean empty )
                            {
                                super.updateItem( item, empty );
                                setText( null );

                                if ( empty )
                                {
                                    setGraphic( null );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // select/unselect the item when checkbox is selected/unselected
                                    checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue )
                                        {
                                            getTableView().requestFocus();
                                            if ( newValue )
                                            {
                                                getTableView().getSelectionModel().select( getIndex() );
                                                list.add( item );
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                getTableView().getSelectionModel().clearSelection( getIndex() );
                                                list.remove( item );
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } );

                                    // select/unselect the checkbox when the tablerow is selected/unselected
                                    if ( getTableRow() != null )
                                    {
                                        getTableRow().selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue )
                                            {
                                                checkBox.setSelected( newValue );
                                                if ( newValue )
                                                {
                                                    list.add( item );
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    list.remove( item );
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } );
                                    }
                                    setGraphic( checkBox );
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                } );

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn( "First Name" );
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth( 100 );
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "firstName" ) );

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn( "Last Name" );
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth( 100 );
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "lastName" ) );

        table.setItems( data );
        table.getColumns().addAll( selectCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol );

        (( Group ) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll( new VBox( table ) );

        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }


    public static class Person
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;


        private Person( String fName, String lName )
        {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty( fName );
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty( lName );
        }


        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }


        public void setFirstName( String fName )
        {
            firstName.set( fName );
        }


        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }


        public void setLastName( String fName )
        {
            lastName.set( fName );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Harshitha what kind of error you are having? Try first to copy-paste all code without modification.

Comment: i have tried with the same code without modifications. Firstly, checkbox is not coming in the first colum of the table.

Comment: @Harshitha. What is your OS and JavaFX versions? Try to clean and build the project.

Comment: win 7 & netbeans 8 inbuilt javafx

Comment: Well @Harshitha, I have not so much idea what is happening. Try adding the selectCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("dummy"));