# How to set up an event listener for a CheckBoxTableCell that's originally a BooleanProperty column to ensure value actually updates?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an eventtable TableView, and I have a StudentGuardian class that has:

```
        private SimpleStringProperty studentName;
        private BooleanProperty hasGuardian;
        private SimpleStringProperty guardianName;
```

In my Controller, I've set it up so that the BooleanProperty is turned into a checkbox, like this:

```
    public void setupCheckbox(){
        hasGuardianTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(c.getValue().getHasGuardian()));
        hasGuardianTableColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());

        eventtable.setEditable(true);
    }
```

It actually works fine, the checkbox turns up and I can check/uncheck it. But it's not actually updating the value of the BooleanProperty when the user clicks the checkbox.

I tried to do this on the same method as the setupCheckbox:

```
hasGuardianTableColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(hasGuardianTableColumn));
        hasGuardianTableColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<StudentGuardian, Boolean> t)
                -> (t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setHasGuardian(t.getNewValue())
        );
```

But it's not working, and I know that since it's not an event listener. I'm really not sure how I'd set up an event listener for the CheckBox since it seems to only be enclosed in that method so I don't know how to reference it. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726824/javafx-event-triggered-when-selecting-a-check-box), but again, I can't reference the new CheckBoxTableCell. I'm also wondering if I should put it in the @Override, or maybe I'm doing it wrong with the way to set it up (or I'm asking the wrong question). Anything helps.

Comment: Don’t create a new Boolean property in the cell value factory.  hasGuardian is already a Boolean property.

Comment: To elaborate on @jewelsea's comment, the check box will update the property returned by the cell value factory. Since you create a new property on the fly each time that is invoked, and don't have any other reference to the property, you have no possible way to persist the effect of the check box being [un]selected. Just return the existing property from the `StudentGuardian` instance.

Comment: Oh, I get that I need to use the existing property from the StudentGuardian. But how do I do that though? I have getters from StudentGuardian but I'm not sure how to implement that on setCellValueFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CheckBoxTableCell` does not work via the "normal" editing mechanism. Here is what [its documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html) says:

> To construct an instance of this class, it is necessary to provide a `Callback` that, given an object of type `T`, will return an `ObservableProperty<Boolean>` that represents whether the given item is selected or not. This `ObservableValue` will be bound bidirectionally (meaning that the `CheckBox` in the cell will set/unset this property based on user interactions, and the `CheckBox` will reflect the state of the `ObservableValue`, if it changes externally).

<sup>**Note:** I assume `ObservableProperty<Boolean>` is simply a typo and `ObservableValue<Boolean>` is what was intended.</sup>

However, this documentation does not match [the implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.java) or API very well. The design of the API is also not the greatest.

1. The callback is not defined to accept `T` but rather `Integer` (the index of the item/cell).
2. Bidirectional binding only works between `Property` objects, so the callback should really be defined to return `Property<Boolean>`.
3. Defining the callback is not actually "necessary", as the implementation will fall back to the column's cell-value factory if no callback is given.
4. The implementation actually only works if the callback/cell-value factory returns a `BooleanProperty`, not just any `ObservableValue<Boolean>` (or even `Property<Boolean>`).

Since your model class itself defines the `BooleanProperty` you want linked with the cells, the easiest solution is to define a cell-value factory that returns the property:

```java
column.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().hasGuardianProperty());
```

But you could instead go with the callback:

```java
column.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(
        index -> table.getItems().get(index).hasGuardianProperty()));
```

---

Note both snippets of code above assume your model class is following the expected "JavaFX Bean" convention. For example, if you have a `Person` class with a "name" property, the class would look like:

```java
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {

  private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");

  // setter (only if property is writable)
  public final void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
  }

  // getter
  public final String getName() {
    return name.get();
  }

  // property getter
  public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is it! It took some modification as I realized I need to get a getter for the BooleanProperty itself, but it works perfectly! Thank you so much!